# Jupyter nbconvert (conda) on mac produces pdf on command line but not from web server

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter, tex

Forgive the newbie question. When I run the following command line:

```
jupyter nbconvert --to pdf "Sales analysis.ipynb"
```

And I get the following output

```
[NbConvertApp] Converting notebook Sales analysis.ipynb to pdf
[NbConvertApp] Support files will be in Sales analysis_files/
[NbConvertApp] Making directory Sales analysis_files
[NbConvertApp] Making directory Sales analysis_files
[NbConvertApp] Writing 56862 bytes to notebook.tex
[NbConvertApp] Building PDF
[NbConvertApp] Running xelatex 3 times: ['xelatex', 'notebook.tex']
[NbConvertApp] Running bibtex 1 time: ['bibtex', 'notebook']
[NbConvertApp] WARNING | bibtex had problems, most likely because there were no citations
[NbConvertApp] PDF successfully created
```

I successfully produce a PDF from an ipython notebook. However, in the notebook server, it produces the following error:

```
nbconvert failed: xelatex not found on PATH, if you have not installed xelatex you may need to do so. Find further instructions at https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#installing-tex.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/nbconvert/handlers.py", line 104, in get
    "config_dir": self.application.settings['config_dir'],
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/pdf.py", line 175, in from_notebook_node
    rc = self.run_latex(tex_file)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/pdf.py", line 137, in run_latex
    self.latex_count, log_error)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/pdf.py", line 99, in run_command
    "at {link}.".format(formatter=command_list[0], link=link))
OSError: xelatex not found on PATH, if you have not installed xelatex you may need to do so. Find further instructions at https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#installing-tex.
```

Why would it run on the command line but not in the notebook server?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No I didn't, but I ended up re-installing and it worked.